# Web.xml servlet-class references to non-existent class "ClassName"

Tags: servlets, jakarta-ee, wildfly, web.xml

I am working on a project and hit a brick wall. I couldn't find any resources or bug reports to solve this issue. I have a maven project setup as maven-archetype-webapp. I am new to JEE and it took me sometime to get this far but I have a better understanding of how some of this works. I have hit a brick wall and don't know how to solve the problem below.

I get the following warnings within the web.xml file

```
servlet-class references to non-existent class "servlets.RegisterServlet"

servlet-class references to non-existent class "servlets.HomePageServlet"

file name references to "index" that does not exist in web content
```

I get the following error in WildFly 10.x.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: servlets.RegisterServlet from [Module "deployment.PracticeProject.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:723)
    ... 6 more
```

The java classes appear in the directory structure of the war so its packaging it correctly. For the entities, session beans and servlets I have a scope of provided for the dependencies of the pom.xml file.

[image]

My directory structure is as follows:

[image]

My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>PracticeProject</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.HomePageServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HomePageServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern></url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

edit:

```
 CHKJ3013E: The URL Mapping "" is invalid.  web.xml /PracticeProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF    org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.webapplication.internal.impl.ServletMappingImpl@53667dce (urlPattern: , name: null)    Validation Message
```

Comment: What does your IDE says? There is a red cross on the web.xml

Comment: @simas_ch please see edit

Comment: Can you try to remove the servlet mapping and the servlet from the web.xml and add the @WebServlet annotation to your servlets?

Comment: thank you, that fixed my problem. I thought that you needed both the @WebServlet annotation and the servlet defined in the web.xml. So i dont even really need the web.xml file then.....

Comment: oh you had both :-) no the web.xml is no longer necessary if you just have some servlets